# New-Cache parameters for AppFabric Cache when storing ASP.NET Session State

Tags: asp.net, caching, appfabric

What are the "optimal" parameters for creating an AppFabric cache when you will be storing session state in the cache?  [MSDN Cache-Related Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718177.aspx#cache)

Powershell command line:

```
New-Cache [-CacheName] <String> [-Eviction <String>] [-Expirable <String>] [-Force [<SwitchParameter>]] [-NotificationsEnabled <String>] [-Secondaries <Int32>] [-TimeToLive <Int64>]
```

- CacheName: < application name >-session-state
- Secondaries: 1 (High Availability turned on in case of server failure)
- Eviction: ?
- Expireable: ?
- TimeToLive: ?
- Force: ?
- NotificationsEnabled: ?

Since I don't want my sessions to be removed unless the session has been abandoned either via code or Session Timeout...

For eviction, I would think "None" and for expireable, I would think False.

I have tested and calling Session.Abandon does remove the object from the cache. I have also tested to see if by extending my session, the session object in cache is also extended.  This does seem to work the "correct" way.

Answer (score 3):

A [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/velocity/thread/48469c46-2ec8-4c64-b441-86e1fa1c846d) from a MS employee confirms my findings.

> 2) Since your question is in the context
>   of session state, when you use the
>   session state provider, the session
>   object is stored in the cache with a
>   timeout equal to the ASP.Net session
>   timeout. Each time the session is
>   accessed, the timeout of the session
>   object in the cache is also reset to
>   the session timeout. It is made sure
>   that the session object expires from
>   the cache only when the ASP.Net
>   session times-out.session times-out.

I still need to create a named cache to get High Availability, but looks like I can leave the other settings to default.

```
New-Cache projectname-session-state -Secondaries 1
```

Comment: Still [no documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859(v=azure.10).aspx) on this, no surprise AppFabric is being deprecated.